# HTTP Server Programming

Tags: c, multithreading, http, sockets

I'm attempting to write my own http 1.1 server, just for fun and learning about more about HTTP, sockets, and threading.

I've gotten a good start i think with only delivering static pages (using c, which I would prefer to stay in for the time being).  I have a test page I wrote a while ago and deliver it's ~50 files in 124ms according to chrome, without using threads or keep-alive sockets.

I've found it very difficult to get threading/keep-alive working at all.  There are little to no resources on the web (that I can find in my hours of Googling) that explain keep-alive connections in detail.  If anyone could recommend a good book on HTTP server programming, I would greatly appreciate it.

I've done some threading and socket programming before by making a simple chat program, so I have at least some experience with it.

The issue I'm having is that when I attempt to incorporate threads, the client browser sets up multiple connections.  Somewhere along the line, the server gets confused and the client just sits there waiting for responses and the server stops doing anything.  I send the Connection: Keep-Alive header, but that doesn't change anything and when I incorporate keep-alive it and create a loop for getting requests in the threaded function, it stalls until the connection is closed.

I would appreciate it if someone could give me some pseudo code on how to get keep alive/threading working for this so the client stops creating multiple connections at a time.

A brief description of whats going on:

`main function`

```
 load in static pages to large array of fileinfo struct that hold the file data and length  
 create the socket
 set it to listen to port 80
 set it to listen for 10 connections at a time(i know this is low...)
 start an endless loop
      block while waiting for someone to connect
      check if it's a localhost connection
          shutdown the server
      otherwise
           start a thread(with pthread), sending it the socket variable
 loop
```

`Thread Function`

```
 setsock opt for 3 sec timeout on send/recv and enable Keep-alive  
 start endless loop
    read in request  
    if request timed out, break the loop  
    Validate Request function call  
    Create Reponse function call  
    Send response  
    if request contained Connection: close header break the loop  
loop  
close socket  
return
```

Comment: How about RFC2616 http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-8.1 ?

Comment: Are you sure it's a threading related issue? Also are you setting the Content-Length header? I think it's required for keep alive to work (unless you use chunking).

Comment: I am using the content-length header also and it is sending the proper size for each message.  The only reason I say it is thread related is that i have no issues until i start using threads.  If i try implementing keep-alive without threads it just takes the page forever to deliver.

Comment: It's really hard to say. If your code works for one connection on a single thread it shouldn't be too hard to make it work with multiple threads as well. Make sure that your threads share a minimum of global state and that access to global resources is properly synchronized. For serving static HTTP contents I think you could ideally design your code so that each thread use no shared memory or resources after being spawned.

Comment: The only obvious keep-alive/threading issue I can think of is that you have to respond to pipelined requests in the order they're issued. So if you sit reading the socket and handing off each request to helper threads to process, make sure you synchronise the writes correctly. Also, clients will tend to create multiple connections with or without persistence. The RFC says 2 per client, but I believe more is common (the value I have in Firefox for network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server is 6), and anyway servers need to support more than that from proxies.

Comment: Hmm, i'll have to look into the timing.  I create a thread per connection and each of those threads just loops through the requests in the order they are received.  Not quite sure how to manage timing with this setup.  The only data the threads access globally is the array with the loaded files (i don't have it checking for updated files atm, so it never changes right now, effectively read only).

Comment: You should give more implementation details.Your server should listen on a specific port, and once a connection is established, then it passes the request (i.e. client socket) to a thread to handle it. The main server waits for connections and separate threads handle each connection.If you want to implement HTTP1.1 permanent connections, then all you have to do (as a start) is not close the connections.

Comment: A brief description of implementation, I could give, but would look ugly in this comment box. Will add to the main post.

Comment: Figured it out.  Wasn't an issue with timing at all, was with threading and failing to pass the socket variable in such a way that it was thread safe.

Comment: You don't **have to** spawn multiple threads / process to deal with concorrent requests - have a look at the select multiplexer - http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking at [GNU libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/). It focuses squarely on providing a framework upon which to build HTTP 1.1 servers. It is small and supports keep-alive with and without threading. (Personally I use it without threading. It has several threading models too.)

Even if you decide to write your web server from scratch, I would suggest looking at [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) to gain insight in not only how the protocol works, but how the library models "the work flow" of a web server in a very clean way. I think it is a mistake to imagine that keep-alive implies threading and I think it is an impediment to understanding keep-alive.

(Regarding Apaches' credits as a web server, it is pretty huge, and there is a *lot* in there not related to protocols, but rather things like its plugin system and so on.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend grabbing the source for Apache and seeing how they handle it.  There's not much point in psuedo code when you can see how the real thing works.

Comment: our answers must have passed in the tubes :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could look at [Apache's code](http://projects.apache.org/projects/http_server.html) for some clues. It is written in C.

Hopefully someone will come along and give a more detailed answer :)

Comment: I am trying to avoid doing this as much as possible.  I started to the other day, but filtering things that I don't need to know at the moment from things I need to are very time consuming.